# JSF SelectOneMenu no reaction to OnValueChanged

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I have this lines of code, where I can select a skin.

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="dropdownSkin"
        value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.name}" defaultLabel="Select a skin.."
        valueChangeListener="#{helloBean.skinValueChanged}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.mySkinsSI}" var="c"
            itemValue="#{c.value}" immediate="true" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <br />

    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.name}"></h:inputText>
    <br />
    <h:inputText id="tcolor" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.tcolor}"></h:inputText>
    <br />
    <h:inputText id="bcolor" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.bcolor}"></h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

But I debugged it and it never goes into my method:

```
public void skinValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    currentSkin = (Skin) e.getNewValue();
}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `onchange` attribute on `f:selectItems` tag. Migrate your `onchange` attribute to `h:selectOneMenu` and this should work.

`h:selectOneMenu` is generated as HTML `select` tag, and `f:selectItems` are `option` tags. So `onchange` really should be in `select` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving on Change in f:selectItems component, try to give **onchange="submit()"** for **h:selectOneMenu** component and try. It should work.